# In Vtiger7 what is the location of edit.js file of vtigercrm/index.php?module=Leads&view=Edit

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am new in Vtiger. I want to Set Designation to Lead Source (Dropdown list) .selected Value. But i can not find `edit.js` file in this path `layout>v7>modules>leads>resources>`??? here only `Details.js` available.
I have open `vtigercrm\layouts\v7\modules\Vtiger\resources\Edit.js` here is get the file but no field is getting.

What i do ?

Comment: I think you can create a file called Edit.js in vtigercrm/moduloes/leads/resources/ (you must create the resources directory). There you can put your custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Create new Edit.js file in `/layouts/vlayout/modules/Leads/resources/`

And format of your js file will be look like as below:

```
Vtiger_Edit_Js("Leads_Edit_Js",{
},{

getLeadSource : function(container) {
    var thisInstance = this;
    var form = jQuery('#EditView');
    var lead_source = container.find("select[name='lead_source_field_name_here'] :selected").val();
    console.log(lead_source);
}

    /**
 * Function which will register basic events which will be used in quick create as well
 *
 */
registerBasicEvents : function(container) {
        this._super(container);
        this.getLeadSource(container);

    } });
```